# Inserting output of hashbytes() function into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hashbytes

I have a table called `tbenc`. Want to insert a value in the `Name` column which should be hash encrypted using `hashbytes()` T-SQL function.

```
create table tbenc
(
    Id int not null identity,
    Name varchar(300) null,
) 

declare @var nvarchar(200)
select @var = hashbytes('sha1', 'Nora')
print @var
insert into tbenc values(@var)
```

When I run:

```
select * from tbenc
```

It shows ?-s instead of the hash code.

[image]

Can anyone point out my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [varbinary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
declare @var varbinary(200)
select @var = hashbytes('sha1', 'Nora')
print @var;
```